# how to close currently created cmd.exe*32 and conhost.exe*32 using java code after execution of java program?

Tags: java, cmd, webobjects

Actually i am running webobjects program through WOMonitor 5.4. If i execute program through WOMonitor then after instance up it creates two more exe (i.e. cmd.exe*32 and conhost.exe*32) that run in Task Manager  as a process and it consumes more memory. For one instance it creates one cmd.exe*32 and conhost.exe*32 but on server i  start 100 or 200 instance so create more cmd.exe*32 and conhost.exe*32. So please anybody help me.

Note: i want to see through java program that how many processes have been executed if i run a java program?  If any method and java program any body has then please send me because this will help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able do that with [Runtime.exec(String command)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) by using the same type of commands that you would normally use to kill a process using Command Prompt.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill cmd.exe*32");
```

If you want to check what processes are created, you could parse the command results of `tasklist`.

```
Program tasklist = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist");
InputStream programOutput = tasklist.getInputStream();
// parse programOutput in whatever way you want
```

Comment: this method will kill all the cmd.exe*32 running. but my concern is  other.

Comment: i want to kill only those cmd which has been created by current program. Let say i run 2 program A and B both has generated cmd  and i want to kill cmd of A by the program of A and cmd of B by  B program (i.e by it's own program)